# Programmatically define WPF DataGrid column width to 100%

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to set the last column of a DataGrid to be 100% of remaining width.

When defining a DataGrid using XAML, I do this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
```

But I have some situation that I'm using c# code to create the columns.

How to set the width of a column to be something like:

```
myColumn.Width = *; ?
```

Comment: Don't be fooled by the duplicate. `GridLength` and `DataGridLength` are different types, the solution is just similar in structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

Comment: Ah, beat me by a second ;)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer and I even had to google it before posting :D